# Javascript does not send data to the output

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a JavaScript when the selected value in a dropdown is changed. But the script isnt working.

Here is my dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Status</label>
    <div>
      <select class="form-control select2" id="data" name="data" style="width: 100%;">
        <option value="1">Data one</option>
        <option value="0">Data two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataEl = document.querySelector('#data'),
    outputEl = document.querySelector('#output');

    dataEl.onchange = function() {
      outputEl.innerHTML = dataEl.value 
        if (1 === dataEl.value) { '<b>Value one</b>' }
        if (0 === dataEl.value) { '<b>Value two</b>' }
  };
</script>
```

When the selected value = 1 the script needs to send `<b>Value one</b>` to the output. When the selected value = 0 the script needs to send `<b>Value two</b>` to the output.

The output looks like:

I also tried to add `selected` to the options, but the script still not sends the data to the output.

Does someone know what is wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/7fa84ufc/

Comment: move your p.output before the script in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. I made a couple changes:

1. I changed the second option's value to "2" instead of "0".
2. I compared the value against the strings "1" and "2" instead of the numbers 1 and 2.
3. I added code to actually change the HTML in the output paragraph.
4. I put an initial value of `<b>Value one</b>` in the output paragraph so it shows when the page is initially loaded.

Your fiddle is also broken because the output paragraph doesn't exist at the point the JavaScript is executed. Move that above the script.

```js
var dataEl = document.querySelector('#data'),
    outputEl = document.querySelector('#output');

dataEl.onchange = function() {
  if (dataEl.value === "1") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<b>Value one</b>';
  } else if (dataEl.value === "2") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<b>Value two</b>';
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Status</label>
  <div>
    <select id="data" name="data">
      <option value="1">Data one</option>
      <option value="2">Data two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="output" name="output"><b>Value one</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<select>` element `.value` is a string, not a number. Use `==` operator for `1 == "1"`

```
dataEl.onchange = function() {
    if (dataEl.value == 1) { outputEl.innerHTML = '<b>Value one</b>' }
    if (dataEl.value == 0) { outputEl.innerHTML = '<b>Value two</b>' }
};
```

Comment: That is due to `#output` not being defined before `<script>` element https://jsfiddle.net/rxfvoreu/2/